# How to save image with new drawn lines in its original quality in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to draw ten lines on my picture and then save it with the new lines but with the same quality and without the white frame from MATLAB, how can i do that?

[image]

```
clear all;
clc



% read the image " its size 3000*4000"
Image = imread('55-3_a.jpg');
% show the image
imshow(Image)


% here i choose two points to draw the lines from them
first_point = [1.452032968374603e+03, 1.446231354344933e+03];
second_point = [0, 4000];

% here i draw ten dashed lines
for line_number = 1: 10
   hold on
   line( second_point  ,first_point - (line_number* 20), 'Color','red','LineWidth', 0.001,'LineStyle','--')
    hold off
end
% and here i draw the normal line
line( [0 4000],[1455, 1455],'Color','red','LineWidth',0.0001);


% here i want to save the image with its new lines with the same quality
% and without any white frame from MATLAB
```

Comment: The best way would be not using MATLAB plots at all, and writting lines into `Image`. Plots are for user visualization, not data modification

Comment: I tried biefore insertShape but since i wanted to draw many lines (with 0.0001 width) it didn't work out and it only accepts integers for width of the line. Do you know a better alternative?

Comment: yo can not write in an image something smaller than a pixel. Unless you resize the image first.

Comment: “with 0.0001 width” — what units? 0.0001 cm? How big is each pixel?

Comment: Whether if you use `plot`, `line`, or `insertShape` the concept of linewidth is the same. Obviously you cannot have a line thinner than your pixel's width.

Comment: yes it's true the concept is the same and it makes sense this way, but it didn't actually work with insertShape but it did with plot. The only solution for me until now isto make the fourth parameter of the method "print" as high as possible